# How to output only the firstname in a name column in Laravel

Tags: php

Have been having issues on how to attract the firstname from a full name from my user table in the name column for output..

for example, full name is John Smith.

Dear JOhn,

How do I do that in laravel.. I have no idea

Comment: you need to pass the model to the view and then you can access the variable in your views. Go through the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views

Comment: Instead of storing the full name you might want to consider storing firstname and lastname separately and concatenating the fullname when needed

Answer (score 3):

Use `strtok()` to get first word from string:

```
$myvalue = 'John Smith';
$firstName= strtok($myvalue, ' ');
```

Comment: but if the person only submitted a name only, hope it wont flag any error?

Comment: @adesure No, if the only name is not working so I have an update answer. Use `strtok()`

Comment: the later now flag an error... the former dosnt output anything if it is just name

Comment: @adesure Sorry third argument not required. remove it

Comment: wow!!! you are the best, it is now working

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if there is a way to do that in Laravel. You could use string functions instead:

```
$first_name = substr($Model->name, 0, strpos($Model->name, " "))
```

Where `$Model` is a Laravel Eloquent model.

Answer (score 2):

assuming `$x = 'John Smith'`.

```
$firstName= explode(" ", $x);
echo $firstName[0];
```

It's a php thing, not a Laravel thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `strtok` function

```
$value = "John Smith";
    echo strtok($value, " ");
```